# Show higher resolution tiles at earlier map zoom levels in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm working on an OpenLayers based site that is loading tiles from our WMTS service. The tiles are satellite images and we provide them at 7 different resolutions (~42km, ~16km, ~8km, ~4km, ~2km, ~1km, ~500m). Some of our beta testers have said that they expected to see higher resolution imagery at certain zoom levels. For example at the View's zoom level 4 they might expect to see an image resolution of ~2km but due to the calculations in OpenLayers are actually being shown the ~4km resolution tiles. So for each zoom level (or intermediate zoom level) show the next higher resolution instead of the lower resolution. Is there some way to tweak OpenLayers to do this?

I read the API docs about zoom levels but it wasn't clear to me if this was possible (min/maxResolution, zoomFactor, etc). The SO questions I found seemed to suggest trying options on the source that don't exist for a WMTS source and aren't exactly what I'm trying to do. I wouldn't be surprised if this is super simple too but I'm misunderstanding the connection between map/view zoom levels and layer zoom levels.

Comment: On a normal device one pixel on a tile will correspond to one pixel on the screen, so attempting to display more detail won't work well.  But if you are viewing on retina devices you could treat 512 pixel tiles as retina tiles for a 256 pixel tile grid, or 256 pixel tiles as retina tiles for a 128 pixel tile grid (in the tile grid setup if you use half the normal tile size you would need to double the resolutions).

Comment: Ok, thanks. We will look in to that. We are using MapCache which doesn't have an option for advertising one size image but providing a different size (AFAIK). I suppose we'll have to create our TileGrid objects with a specific size depending on the users HiDPI options.